# Batch: Pipe command output to variable and compare

Tags: batch-file

I try to pipe my command output to variables and then compare if those variables have the same value. However it always return both variables have same value(even though it is not). Below is my code:

```
@echo off
goto main

:main
setlocal

echo 111 | (set /p readvalue= & set readvalue)
echo 123 | (set /p readvaluebash= & set readvaluebash)
if "%readvalue%"=="%readvaluebash%" goto valid
if NOT "%readvalue%"=="%readvaluebash%" goto invalid

:valid
echo yes
pause
goto finish

:invalid
echo no
pause
goto finish


:finish
endlocal
```

I always get the `yes` result. Anyone know my mistake here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Protect your subroutines; make sure there's an unconditional `goto` before each entry point. Also, troubleshoot by trying to `echo` the values of the variables.

Comment: try `echo 111`, next line `set /p readvalue= & set readvalue`, next line `echo 123`, next line `set /p readvaluebash= & set readvaluebash`, or to say it easy line after line not `echo 123 | (set....)`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you run (same for the other line)

```dos
echo 111 | (set /p readvalue= & set readvalue)
```

you see that the value shown in console as the variable value is `111`, so the `set /p` was able to retrieve the piped data.

The problem is that the pipe operator starts two separate `cmd` instances: one running the left part (`echo`) of the pipe and another running the right part (`set /p`).

As each process has its own environment space and as the `set /p` is executed in a separate `cmd` instance, any change to any variable in this new `cmd` instace will not change the environment of the `cmd` instance running the batch file.

To store the output of a command in a variable, instead of a pipe you can use a `for /f` command

```dos
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('echo 111') do set "readValue=%%a"
```

Comment: Ah I see! So that means there is no way I can perform the `"%readvalue%"=="%readvaluebash%"` in one batch file? Probably the best workaround is to save into .txt first I guess?

Comment: @GregorIsack, That means you can not use a pipe to change a variable and see the change inside the current batch file. If you need to store in a variable the output of a command use a `for /f` command

Comment: Learned a new thing! Thank you so much!

Comment: How to capture the`%ERRORLEVEL%` from `echo 111` as well?